# TypeScript Node Server vs Web Assembly Server

Tags: node.js, typescript, server, webassembly

When TypeScript is properly strictly typed throughout an application it can compile to Web Assembly.

What are the performance benefits of running your server as a WebAssembly binary vs a running NodeJS server process?

Comment: this seems overly broad -- what are the relative runtime sizes?  You could probably write a book on this topic

Comment: It is very broad of a question. Would be great to start the conversation. @picklerick

Comment: That can hardly be answered here since it's too broad, but if i would guess, the benefits would be negligible, Node V8 engine is highly optimized. Keep in mind that if you need to squeeze that much performance(Wich would raise questions on why do you need that on a web-server) to the point were you're asking this, you probably shouldn't be using NodeJS and should use something on lower-levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the performance benefits of running your server as a WebAssembly binary vs a running NodeJS server process

Note that WebAssembly still needs to run in a container. The current WebAssembly containers are browsers and node

## Correct Question

So the question really is `What is the performance advantage of WebAssembly over JavaScript`.

## Answer

Performance benefits of WebAssembly over JavaScript are covered all over the internet.

*Key Reason*:

WebAssembly is much closer to hardware level programming.

*Levels of proramming langauges*:

i.e. Webassembly is low level: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language and JavaScript is higher level : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language and therefore has overheads.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do I/O from WebAssembly. It is for computation.

You send data into it via a Memory buffer, and get back a memory buffer. See the [JS API sample](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/js-api/index.html#sample) in the docs.

You could use it for a crypto module in a webserver, but not for most of the stuff that the server does.